# Every eigenvector of $T$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$. Prove that $T$ is a normal operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The question is as in the title:

> $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation, $V$ is a finite dimensional vector-space over the complex field.
> Every eigenvector of T is an eigenvector of $T^*$. Prove that T is a normal operator.

I have found the following questions already asked previously, however the answers to them left me kind of stumbled, as they are not fully explained.

[For example in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622168/normal-matrix-and-eigenvectors) which attempted to provide a clearer proof than [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45869/if-every-eigenvector-of-t-is-also-an-eigenvector-of-t-then-t-is-a-norm).

[The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622371/1141957) with the highest votes states in the middle of the proof:

> By the induction assumption, the matrix $\tilde T$  is diagonal since it has
> the same eigenvectors as $\tilde T^∗$ .

Specifically, I couldn't figure out why the following statement is true:

> $\tilde T$ has the same eigenvectors as $\tilde T^*$.

If somebody could explain to me I will be very thankful :)

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT

I've posted an answer below which further breaks down Ben Grossman's answer, and also continues the proof for the original problem.

Comment: Is $V$ a finite dimensionnal?

Comment: @Youem Right it seems I forgot to add this detail. It is given that V is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll pick up from the point in the proof in which the statement arises, in which we have already shown that
$$
T = \pmatrix{\tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T}, \quad T^* = \pmatrix{\bar \tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T^*}.
$$
Note that for any vector $v \in \Bbb C^{n-1}$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb C$, we have
$$
T \pmatrix{\alpha \\ v}= \pmatrix{\tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T} \pmatrix{\alpha \\ v} = \pmatrix{\tau \alpha\\ \tilde Tv}.
$$
Use this to observe that the following statements are equivalent:

- $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T$
- the block-vector $(0,v)$ is an eigenvector of $T$
- the block-vector $(0,v)$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$
- $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T^*$

Thus, $\tilde T$ and $\tilde T^*$ indeed have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Even after reading it, I don't understand why $v$ is necessarily an eigenvector of $\tilde T$. I don't understand why $\pmatrix{0 \\ v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ for any $v \in \Bbb C^{n-1}$.

Following the fact $v \in \Bbb C^{n-1}$ and the final statements, wouldn't it mean that any such $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T$?

Comment: @EmanuelL Regarding "I don't understand why $v$ is necessarily an eigenvector of $\tilde T$": this is a question that I'm not sure how to answer directly because it indicates a fundamental miscommunication, but this might help: the statement "$\tilde T$ has the same eigenvectors as $\tilde T^*$" can be rephrased as "$v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T$ if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T^*$". If you can understand that the four statements I list are equivalent, then you can show that **if** $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ **then** it is an eigenvector of $\tilde T^*$ and vice versa

Comment: @EmanuelL Perhaps it is more helpful to start here. Do you understand what I meant when I wrote "the following statements are equivalent"?

Comment: Actually, after fiddling around with these in my notebook I think I now understand your proof. What confused me is that I thought the $v$ in the statement at the end is the same $v$  as above, (an arbitrary vector in $V$). After understanding that in the statements, $v$ is already an eigenvector of $\tilde T$, everything fell into it's place.
Thank you for the patient explanation!

Comment: I have posted an answer which basically breaks this down completely to the bones (for anyone who might have trouble understanding it). Thank you so much for taking your time answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer above basically solves the problem. However I want to post an answer to completely break down why this happens (especially if anyone has trouble understanding, like I did).

Continuing Ben's answer, we can choose any $v$ such that $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T$. Constructing a new vector $\pmatrix{0 \\ v}$ leads us to:

$$
T \pmatrix{0 \\ v}= \pmatrix{\tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T} \pmatrix{0 \\ v} = \pmatrix{0 \\ \tilde Tv}
$$

From this we can conclude that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T$ then $\pmatrix{0 \\ v}$ is guaranteed to be an eigenvector of $T$.

However, it is given that any eigenvector of $T$ is also an eigenvector of $T^*$. In this case the following applies:

$$
T^* \pmatrix{0 \\ v}= \pmatrix{\overline \tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T^*} \pmatrix{0 \\ v} = \pmatrix{0 \\ \tilde T^*v}
$$

From this we conclude that $\pmatrix{0 \\ v}$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$, only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T^*$.

Hence this shows that any eigenvector of $T$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$.

---

Back to the original problem.

Since now $\tilde T$ is a matrix of $(n-1) \times (n-1)$, and every eigenvector of $\tilde T$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde T^*$, it follows by the induction's assumption that $\tilde T$ is also a diagonal matrix. In this case:

$$
T = \pmatrix{\tau & 0\\0 & \tilde T}
$$

And since both matrix blocks are diagonal, it follows that $T$ is also a diagonal matrix.

Since we have shown that $T$ can be represented in some basis by a diagonal matrix, it follows that $T^*$ can also a represented by a diagonal matrix. Since diagonal matrices commute, we then conclude that $TT^*$=$T^*T$, hence $T$ is a normal operator.